# Declaring a cursor with XML Namespaces (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, xml, cursor, xml-namespaces

I have an XML document with the default namespace `urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02` and I believe I have a need to use a cursor to iterate across a repeated segment.

Here is a very much simplified version of the file:

```
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
  <BkToCstmrStmt>
    <GrpHdr>...</GrpHdr>
    <Stmt>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <CreDtTm>2015-06-23T03:25:08.688+01:00</CreDtTm>
    </Stmt>
    <Stmt>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <CreDtTm>2015-06-23T03:25:09.000+01:00</CreDtTm>
    </Stmt>
    <Stmt>
      <Id>3</Id>
      <CreDtTm>2015-06-23T03:25:10.051+01:00</CreDtTm>
    </Stmt>
  </BkToCstmrStmt>
</Document>
```

I am building upon the advice given in this answer for [SQL 2012 - iterate through an XML list (better alternative to a WHILE loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19034743/2344631).

Without the default `xmlns` I would be able to declare a cursor to iterate across the `stmt` sections like this:

```
declare c cursor fast_forward for
select
    s.c.value('(Id/text())[1]', 'integer') as Id,
    s.c.value('(CreDtTm/text())[1]', 'datetime2(3)') as CreDtTm
from @XML_In.nodes('Document/BkToCstmrStmt') as b(c)
    outer apply b.c.nodes('Stmt') as s(c)
```

which would return this result set:

```
Id  CreDtTm
1   2015-06-23 02:25:08.688
2   2015-06-23 02:25:09.000
3   2015-06-23 02:25:10.051
```

If I were using a plain `select` statement I could declare the default namespace for the query like this (given `@XML_In` is a string representing the XML document):

```
with xmlnamespaces(default 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02')
select
    s.c.value('(Id/text())[1]', 'integer') as Id,
    s.c.value('(CreDtTm/text())[1]', 'datetime2(3)') as CreDtTm
from @XML_In.nodes('Document/BkToCstmrStmt') as b(c)
    outer apply b.c.nodes('Stmt') as s(c)
```

How can I combine the use of a cursor with the need to query within an explicit default namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the example from your linked questions, have you tried a simple combination of the two?

```
DECLARE @XML_in XML = '<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
  <BkToCstmrStmt>
    <GrpHdr>...</GrpHdr>
    <Stmt>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <CreDtTm>2015-06-23T03:25:08.688+01:00</CreDtTm>
    </Stmt>
    <Stmt>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <CreDtTm>2015-06-23T03:25:09.000+01:00</CreDtTm>
    </Stmt>
    <Stmt>
      <Id>3</Id>
      <CreDtTm>2015-06-23T03:25:10.051+01:00</CreDtTm>
    </Stmt>
  </BkToCstmrStmt>
</Document>'


DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
with xmlnamespaces(default 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02')
SELECT s.c.value('(Id/text())[1]', 'integer') AS Id
    ,s.c.value('(CreDtTm/text())[1]', 'datetime2(3)') AS CreDtTm
FROM @XML_In.nodes('Document/BkToCstmrStmt') AS b(c)
OUTER APPLY b.c.nodes('Stmt') AS s(c)

declare @Id int
declare @CreDtTm datetime2(3)
OPEN cur

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    FETCH cur
    INTO @Id
        ,@CreDtTm

    IF @@fetch_status <> 0
        BREAK
    -- Do whatever you like with your cursor
    select @Id, @CreDtTm
END

CLOSE cur

DEALLOCATE cur
```

Results

```
----------- ---------------------------
1           2015-06-23 02:25:08.688

(1 row(s) affected)


----------- ---------------------------
2           2015-06-23 02:25:09.000

(1 row(s) affected)


----------- ---------------------------
3           2015-06-23 02:25:10.051

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I did try a simple combination of the two, but not in the order you've offered. Believe it or not the `for with` part of `declare c cursor local fast_forward for
with xmlnamespaces(default 'urn...')
select...` looked so ugly I assumed it couldn't possibly be right. Thank you.